# Одно трёхзначное натуральное число и уменьшает каждую его цифру на 1

Tags: c++, арифметика

надо програму которая запрашивает одно трёхзначное натуральное число и уменьшает каждую его цифру на 1. Если в числе есть цифра 0, то вместо неё необходимо поставить 9. Если после преобразования в числе появятся ведущие нули, выводить их не надо. В качестве ответа выведите получившиеся число.  Задачу необходимо решить без применения условного оператора.И у меня чет не виходит,вот приклад входних и виходних даних:

Sample Input 1:
123

Sample Output 1:
12

Sample Input 2:
920

Sample Output 2:
819

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, x, y, z;
    cin >> a;
    x = (a / 100 - 1) % 10;
    y = (a / 10 % 10 - 1) % 10;
    z = (a % 10 - 1) % 10;
    cout << x << y << z;
    return 0;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен:)

Comment: Извините не сдержался, но не "входних", а "входнЫх" и т.д. И что именно у вас не получилось? В чем ошибка? Выводит не правильно?

Comment: Чтобы ваш код заработал нужно всюду `- 1` заменить на `+ 9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a;
cin >> a;
a = (a%10+9)%10 + (a/10%10+9)%10*10 + (a/100%10+9)%10*100;
cout << a;
```

Устроит?

Ну, раз уж Arty решил для чисел любой длины, придется поддержать :)

```
unsigned int m111(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int b = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1;a;a/=10,i*=10)
        b = b+(a%10+9)%10*i;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но я думаю что такого вида for использует условный оператор во второй позиции, хоть не со словом if но всё равно это условный оператор. Но всё равно решение хорошее! Это тоже самое как `while (n)` тоже можно считать условным оператором.

Comment: @Arty Ну да, в принципе, на грани фола, но для произвольной длины при любом представлении любой код пусть даже где-то за сценой должен проверять, не кончились ли знаки...

Comment: Если на то пошло то неявные условные if будут в каком угодно коде, хотя бы ввод/вывод в консоле будет внутри использовать if. Другое дело что можно ни одного явного не использовать в решении.

Comment: @Arty ...заменив, например, тернарным оператором :)

Comment: Да спасибо ви очень помогли мне

Answer (score -1):

Решил задачу для произвольного целого неотрицательного числа с любым числом знаков, используя строковые операции и без условных операторов. Может пригодится такой вариант, если разрешается работать со строками а не числами.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/oedqP5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    for (auto & c: s)
        c = (9 + c - '0') % 10 + '0';
    s.erase(0, (s.substr(0, s.size() - 1) + "1").find_first_not_of("0"));
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ввод 1:

```
120
```

Вывод 1:

```
19
```

Ввод 2:

```
7388642125908423233724581410784625211879022397248114511102998551365742
```

Вывод 2:

```
6277531014897312122613470309673514100768911286137003400091887440254631
```

Comment: Тогда уж `std::for_each(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char& c){ c = (9 + c - '0') % 10 + '0';});` :)

Comment: Да, и еще - если число типа 11..11 - то не будет выведено ничего, а по логике все же надо выводить один 0, нет?

Comment: @Harry Да логично, надо поправить.

Comment: @Harry Поправил случай 11111111111.

Comment: Спасибо ви мне очень помогли